# jQuery : XML - Reading child nodes from a specific node

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have an xml file in which i want to read the child nodes of a specific node... Below is the XML file.

The XML file structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<categories>
<category type='Type A'>
    <genre>1</genre>
    <genre>2</genre>
</category>
<category type='Type B'>
     <genre>3</genre>
     <genre>4</genre>
     <genre>5</genre>
</category>
<category type='Type C'>
    <genre>6</genre>
</category>
</categories>
```

An example of what i wouild need using this XML is all the genres for category type B. How exactly could i filter out all the other categories so i could do a **.find("genre").each....** and return only genres 3,4 and 5.

Heres the code im using:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "myxml.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(data){
            xml = data;
            });
        }
    });

    return {getXml : function() 
    { 
        if (xml) return xml;
    }};
})();

/* On Category Change */
$(".category").change(function(){
    var xml = xmlArtists.getXml();

    $(".genre").find("option").remove().end();

    var type = $(this).val();
    var typeGenres = $(xml).find("categories").filter(function(){
        return $(this).find("category").attr("type") == type;
    });

    typeGenres.find("genre").each(function(){
        var genre = $(this).text();
        $(".genre").append("<option value=" + genre + ">" + genre + "</option>");
    });
});
```

The .category is an object when its changed the code should fire... since im poulating another object upon its change but anyways thats not much of importance for this question...

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Just figured it out was easier than i thought... heres the code:

    /* On Category Change */
 $(".category").change(function(){
  var xml = xmlArtists.getXml();
  
  $(".genre").find("option").remove().end();
  
  var type = $(this).val();
  $(xml).find("category[type='" + type + "']").find("genre").each(function(){
   var genre = $(this).text();
   $(".genre").append("<option value=" + genre + ">" + genre + "</option>");
  });
 });

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(xml).find('category[type="Type B"] > genre')
```

This would find all `category` nodes whose `type` is `"Type B"` and get all the `genre` child nodes of each matched category.

Comment: haha ya i was posting that just before you responded but it didnt let me due to my reputation so i put it as a comment. It was easier than i thought... thanks alot anyways!!!